# Solution to recurrence relation for $T(n)=3T(\frac{n}{2}) + \log n$

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have a recurrence relation,

\begin{align}
T(n) & = 1\quad \text{if }n = 1 \\
& = 3T(n/2) + \log_2n \;\; \text{otherwise} 
\end{align}

Now on going with recurrence tree method, I ended with following calculations.

[Recursion tree creation and calculation - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdOYU.jpg)

[Calculation - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nTQk.jpg)

Is it the correct answer? Or should it be rounded to $\Theta(n^2 log\,n)$? Or something else?

I am slightly stuck at calculations so a help on them would be very nice.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. This is a well-written question, but it would be best if you could write your attempts in MathJax (as you did for the recurrence relation) instead of as an image.

Comment: It is $$T_n=c_1 3^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}-1}+\frac{1}{4} \log (2) \left(-\frac{2 \log
   (n)}{\log (2)}+3^{\frac{\log (n)}{\log (2)}+1}-3\right)$$